# SSL Client Authentication in Openshift with Custom SSL Certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, openshift, authentication

Is it possible to use SSL Client Authentication in a Node.js application in OpenShift?

Now that OpenShift supports Custom SSL Certificates (SNI based) from 0$ in its bronze plan, it could be attractive to switch to the bronze plan. However it seems like the client certificate could not be accessed from the application (i.e. node.js). Or is there some hidden flag I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate is actually hosted on an apache reverse proxy on the node, and is not accessible from your gear.  You can look for the x-forwarded-proto header to see if the request is an https request or not.

Comment: Yes the server certificate is hosted on SSL forward proxy, but I'm interested in the client certificate. The proxy is setting the header x-forwarded-ssl-client-cert, but it seems to always be empty (i.e. '') or '(null)'.